# How can I accept specific external room bookings in Outlook without ProcessExternalMettingMessages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meeting-request

I often get meeting invitations in Outlook from people in other interstate companies, inviting myself and several local colleagues in my company to attend a web meeting (via webex or similar). I want to forward this invitation to a local meeting room to book that room.

But the room rejects the invitation because the person who sent the *original* invitation is outside our company.

We don't want to set ProcessExternalMettingMessages to True as we don't want every random person on the internet to be able to book our rooms.

I can make a duplicate meeting and invite the room to the duplicate, and then invite all local staff to the duplicate meeting so they know what local room to come to, but that means we all have duplicate meetings that need to be kept in sync. I can do this if I have to, but I'd far prefer to just forward the original invite to a local room (and have the room accept the invitation).

I actually got myself Owner access to the rooms, but I still can't find a way to actually see the room's email inbox, so I can accept the invitations.

So my questions are:

1. Now that I'm an owner, is there a way I can see the room's email
   inbox, so I can accept the forwarded invitation? Or is there a way I
   can see the invitation in the room's calendar, and accept it from
   there?
2. Is there some other way I can get a room in my company to
   accept a meeting that I forwarded but was originally from an
   external person, without switching on
   ProcessExternalMettingMessages?

Answer (score 0):

> Now that I'm an owner, is there a way I can see the room's email inbox, so I can accept the forwarded invitation? Or is there a way I can see the invitation in the room's calendar, and accept it from there?

For room mailbox, admin can add your account as the booking delegate so that you can accept and decline meeting request.But you may need to process all meeting request.

[image]

> Is there some other way I can get a room in my company to accept a meeting that I forwarded but was originally from an external person, without switching on ProcessExternalMettingMessages?

According to my research, this may be not realized.

Another option is to give your account 'Full Access' to this room mailbox, so that you can check room's Inbox and calendar on Outlook client and manually process the request.

Comment: Thanks Perry, I’ll see if I can get “Full Access” to these rooms.

Your suggestion of booking delegate is a good one, but unfortunately those rooms are so busy I’d spend all day just accepting regular internal requests.